# Baxter simulation with controllers doesn't work

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, baxter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

I haven't been able to run the Baxter simulation with controllers by following the instructions in Baxter simulation installation page ([here](http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/Simulator_Installation)). The only point at which I deviate from the instructions is that I did the installation from the kinetic-devel branch instead of the master branch to support ROS Kinetic as per the suggestions in [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/260560/baxter-installation-error-boost-vs-qt-conflict/). I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with ROS Kinetic. After I was done with the installation and the configuration of the Baxter.sh to include my baxter hostname and my ip, I run the following command:

```
./baxter.sh sim
```

followed by the following command to run the simulator with controllers:

```
roslaunch baxter_gazebo baxter_world.launch
```

Then I Get a long output trace, the notable of which are the following segments:

```
<initialization output omitted>
    [FATAL] [1493505890.694257829, 0.165000000]: No matching hardware interface found for 'hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface' while loading interfaces for right_s0
    [FATAL] [1493505890.697592002, 0.165000000]: Could not initialize robot simulation interface
<initialization output continues ...>
    Warning [parser.cc:437] Converting a deprecated SDF source[data-string].
    [ WARN] [1493505891.721203206]: GazeboRosVideo plugin missing <robotNamespace>, defaults to "".
    [ WARN] [1493505891.721283972]: GazeboRosVideo Plugin (ns = ) missing <topicName>, defaults to "image_raw".
    [ WARN] [1493505891.721298001]: GazeboRosVideo Plugin (ns = ) missing <height>, defaults to 240.
    [ WARN] [1493505891.721319684]: GazeboRosVideo Plugin (ns = ) missing <width>, defaults to 320
    [ INFO] [1493505891.767155891]: GazeboRosVideo (gzclient, ns = ) has started!
    Warning [parser.cc:437] Converting a deprecated SDF source[data-string].
    [ WARN] [1493505892.192849445, 1.312000000]: GazeboRosVideo plugin missing <robotNamespace>, defaults to "".
    [ WARN] [1493505892.192999780, 1.312000000]: GazeboRosVideo Plugin (ns = ) missing <topicName>, defaults to "image_raw".
    [ WARN] [1493505892.193054191, 1.312000000]: GazeboRosVideo Plugin (ns = ) missing <height>, defaults to 240.
    [ WARN] [1493505892.193111982, 1.312000000]: GazeboRosVideo Plugin (ns = ) missing <width>, defaults to 320
    [ INFO] [1493505892.208347135, 1.314000000]: GazeboRosVideo (gzserver, ns = ) has started!
    [ WARN] [1493505902.209672755, 10.303000000]: Topic '/robot/xdisplay' unable to connect to 2 subscribers within 10 sec. It is possible initially published visual messages will be lost.
    [ INFO] [1493505902.351562348, 10.392000000]: Simulator is loaded and started successfully
    gzserver: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:648: typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = controller_manager::ControllerManager; typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type = controller_manager::ControllerManager*]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
    Aborted (core dumped)
    [gazebo-1] process has died [pid 7989, exit code 134, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver -e ode /home/majed/catkin_ws/src/baxter_simulator/baxter_gazebo/worlds/baxter.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/majed/.ros/log/db5978ae-2ca7-11e7-b226-080027ef320b/gazebo-1.log].
    log file: /home/majed/.ros/log/db5978ae-2ca7-11e7-b226-080027ef320b/gazebo-1*.lo
```

Please let me know if more information is needed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260681/baxter-simulation-with-controllers-doesn%27t-work/) by [majedz](https://answers.ros.org/users/30193/majedz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-04-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you follow the ROS Kinetic tabs for the [Prerequisites and Baxter Simulator Installation](http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/Simulator_Installation#Prerequisites) sections? The default tab is Indigo, which will not work in your case.

---

Originally posted by [imcmahon](https://answers.ros.org/users/499/imcmahon/) with karma: 790 on 2017-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [majedz](https://answers.ros.org/users/30193/majedz/) on 2017-05-01**:
@imcmahon Thanks for your help so far. When I followed the instructions for Kinetic, I was able to download all per-requisite packages except for ros-kinetic-driver-common. I get the error `E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-driver-common`. Any hint on what's the problem here please?

**Comment by [majedz](https://answers.ros.org/users/30193/majedz/) on 2017-05-01**:
@imcmahon please note that my sources list file lists the following `deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial main`